# Send Notification Update when firebase database is updated

Tags: android

I am new to android Firebase and I want that when any new value is added to Firebase then I get any notification like your database is updated or so.. How can I do that.. 
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using Push Notification , During Registration,  get the generated token  and save it your database along with user details .
 whenever a key/child is updated 
  fire up the Event to that tokenID

you should have a broadcast Receiver in you application which monitors the  incoming firebase message

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
// Check if message contains a data payload.
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
}

// Check if message contains a notification payload.
if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}
```

}

here is an Example https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/codelab/friendlychat/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

Comment: Can you please explain this Broadcast Receiver ? How can i do that?